# ASP .NET - Not having root node in SiteMap for use in menu?

Tags: asp.net, menu

Using a SiteMap linked up to a Menu (first time for both).

I would like the menu to show horizontally with multiple main options which each have sub options.

So something like this:

[alt text http://ts1.mm.bing.net/images/thumbnail.aspx?q=943731315644&id=e665eb8277e10731ca8ea1b676254170&url=http%3a%2f%2faskehbl.files.wordpress.com%2f2007%2f08%2fdropdown.jpg](http://ts1.mm.bing.net/images/thumbnail.aspx?q=943731315644&id=e665eb8277e10731ca8ea1b676254170&url=http%3a%2f%2faskehbl.files.wordpress.com%2f2007%2f08%2fdropdown.jpg)

Right now I can only have a root SiteMapNode and then main/sub options.

Not like this:

[image]
<sub>(source: [beansoftware.com](http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Images/Menu-XML.jpg))</sub>

Do I need to change the SiteMap or the Menu settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I needed to set the 'StaticDisplayLevels' property of the menu to 2 from the default of 1.
This enables the 'root' and 'main categories' to display horizontally instead of all grouped under the 'root'.

Answer (score 2):

menu setting - Set it's orientation to Horizontal.

Comment: I did that but there still is only one root node allowed - so all I see is Home and then the main categories appear as dropdowns under it instead of showing horizontally.